# Position inside float element

Tags: html, css, css-float

I've made a custom dropdown, here is the HTML:

```
<div class='dropdown'>
    <div class='dropdownTitle'>Sort by<span class='select_arrow'></span></div>
    <ul class='selectPanel'>
        <li><input  type='checkbox' id='allProducts'><label for='allProducts'>Name</label></li>
        <li><input  type='checkbox' id='Enterprise'><label for='Enterprise'>Date</label></li>
        <li><input  type='checkbox' id='Security'><label for='Security'>Popularity</label></li>
        <li><input  type='checkbox' id='Data'><label for='Data'>Rating</label></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is working fine in the most cases, but, if I float the dropdown, the element inside don't show as I would expected: the width of the panel don't grow when the labels are bigger. I've made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qtp49/1/).

Can anybody explain to me why this is happening, and how to solve?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you need to describe the desired result a little more clearly.

Comment: look at the fiddle it makes sense

Comment: You can see the desired result in the jsfiddle (the dropdown with the label 'correct'). The <li> element shouldn't broke in two lines (one with the checkbox and below the label) but should stay all in one line.

Comment: Try to specify the width of the floated element, such as     
#second {
    float:right;
    width:150px;
}
Is this solve your problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `white-space: nowrap;` to your CSS:

```
.dropdown {
    display : inline-block;
    font-size: 12px;
    color : #646464;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this by adding `white-space: nowrap` to your `li`. Something like this:

```
.dropdown>ul>li {
    margin : 0;
    padding : 0;
    padding : 0 8px;
    display : block;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

This prevents the two inline blocks (label and input) from appearing on a different line.

Answer (score 0):

Hey so basically when you are using the `float:right` as many thing will appear on a row as possible if the element that does not fit will be pushed to the next row.

So the easy fix is have to set a width for `.dropdown>ul>li` in this case `width : 140px;` works for this fiddle but it will depend on the longest text length in the list

here is how it now look's in [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qtp49/1/)